# Setting up simple internal server using docker is giving me database errors ((sqlite3.OperationalError or path not found)

Tags: docker, sqlite

I am trying to humanize antibodies using biophi. I set up an simplified server using Docker as suggested on their github page (https://github.com/Merck/BioPhi).

The code to run the server should look like this:
docker run 
-v /your/absolute/path/to/oasis/directory/:/data 
-e OASIS_DB_PATH=/data/OASis_9mers_v1.db 
-p 5000:5000 
quay.io/biocontainers/biophi:1.0.5--pyhdfd78af_0 
biophi web --host 0.0.0.0

If I use the following code to set up the server:
docker run -v C:\OAS -e OASIS_DB_PATH=C:\OAS -p 5000:5000 quay.io/biocontainers/biophi:1.0.5--pyhdfd78af_0 biophi web –-host 0.0.0.0

The .db file is in the folder OAS.

This works to get the server running, but once I start humanizing
I get the following error on the internal server: Error: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

I tried reformatting the docker run command line:

docker run -v C:\OAS -e OASIS_DB_PATH=C:\OAS\oas.db -p 5000:5000 quay.io/biocontainers/biophi:1.0.5--pyhdfd78af_0 biophi web –-host 0.0.0.0 but to no avail since I am probably formatting the line wrong. Error: The OASis DB path does not exist

I hope somebody can advise me how to get the database connected to the server.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If your db file on your machine is C:\OAS\oas.db, then you should map the C:\OAS directory into the container at some path (the example uses `/data`) and then use the db filename `/data/oas.db` inside the container. Something like `docker run -v C:\OAS:/data -e OASIS_DB_PATH=/data/oas.db -p 5000:5000 quay.io/biocontainers/biophi:1.0.5--pyhdfd78af_0 biophi web --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you Hans!